# Tap event on a ui-block is not firing - JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mouseevent

I have a piece of code:

On HTML body:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <section class="ui-grid-c">
      <div class="ui-block-a">Column 1</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">Column 2</div>
      <div class="ui-block-c">Column 3</div>
      <div class="ui-block-d">Column 4</div>
      <div class="ui-block-a">Column 1</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">Column 2</div>
      <div class="ui-block-c">Column 3</div>
      <div class="ui-block-d">Column 4</div>
      <div class="ui-block-a">Column 1</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">Column 2</div>
      <div class="ui-block-c">Column 3</div>
      <div class="ui-block-d">Column 4</div>
      <div class="ui-block-a">Column 1</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">Column 2</div>
      <div class="ui-block-c">Column 3</div>
      <div class="ui-block-d">Column 4</div>
    </section>
    <button id="show">Show</button>
</div>
```

and on JQM side:

```
var word = "";

$(document).on('tap', 'ui-block-a', function(e){                        
                    word = word + $(this).text();
                });
$(document).on('click', '#show', function(e){                        
                    alert(word);
                    word = "";
                });
```

This part:

```
$(document).on('tap', 'ui-block-a', function(e)
```

is not firing as expected.If I replace  `word = word + $(this).text();` with `alert($(this).text());` no alert window is showing up.

Another question is if I want write a tap event handler on 'ui-block-b' a seperate event handler must be written to handle this event? I want to call the same function  `$(document).on('tap', 'ui-block-a', function(e)` when a tap event occurs in any of ui-blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an typo. In `$(document).on('tap', 'ui-block-a', function(e){`, it should be `.ui-block-a` instead of `ui-block-a`.

For the second question. I have two suggestions.

First is to use a common class for all these `<div>` and bind this event to this common class.

For example, add a class named `word-add` to all the `<div>`.

```
<div class="ui-block-a word-add">Column 1</div>
```

and then bind the tap event on `word-add`

```
$(document).on('tap', 'word-add', function(e){...})
```

The second is to define a function first and bind this function to tap event.

```
function addWord(e){
    word = word + $(this).text();
}

$(document).on('tap', 'ui-block-a', addWord);
$(document).on('tap', 'ui-block-b', addWord);
```

Comment: That was a typo.Any answer on second part of the question.